# Doing group_by on class with belongs_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `course` which has_many `subcategories`. I want to build a page that shows courses grouped by their subcategory. So far, I have

`@courses = Course.personal_enrichment.order('subcategory_id').page params[:page]`
`@courses_facet = @courses.group_by(&:subcategory_id)`

which works fine, but I need to show the actual subcategory name in the view, not the number. I've seen some other answers about this type of thing, but most of them assume the attribute you're grouping by is already human readable. Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rendering the view you can just access the referenced models' attributes. Since `group_by` returns a hash, you could do something like this:

```
<% @courses_facet.each do |subcategory_id, courses| %>
  <% subcategory_name = courses.first.subcategory.name rescue nil %>
  <label><%= subcategory_name %></label>
<% end%>
```

Unless relevant subcategory models are cached this will generate N+1 queries to fetch the subcategory names. One way to avoid that is to include subcategory records to the initial resultset.

```
@courses.includes(:subcategories).group_by(&:subcategory_id)
```